# Using regular expression to match a row which contains a certain word and is the last line of the string

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I would like to find a regular expression that will match a row, which contains a certain word (or character) and is the last line of the string.

Any ideas on how I could do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Generally, with problems of this nature, we expect posters to demonstrate their latest attempt at solving this problem.  Can you post any regex you have attempted thus far?

Comment: What do you mean by row, last line? Where are you using this regex, PHP, javascript, etc.?

Comment: where's the row ? and the word ? and what have you tried already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to use the fact that the dot doesn't match newlines.
You can use this kind of pattern:

```
.*?TARGET.*$
```

or to isolate the target:

```
TARGET(?=.*$)
```

---

**Notices:**

You have to take care that the multiline mode (the m modifier for the most regex engines) isn't activated, otherwise `$` will match the end of a line (and not the end of the string in particular).

If available, prefer to use the `\z` anchor instead of `$` because in Perl compatible regex engine, `$` succeeds also before a trailing newline sequence (however you can also take advantage of this flexibility):

```
.*?TARGET.*\z
```

Comment: Isn't the "dot not matching newlines" a language specific feature?

Comment: @BlackVegetable: I do not know all the languages/apps of the universe, but as far I know, all languages by default are set like that.

Comment: *match a row* - you'd need to add `.*` at the beginning. `.*TARGET.*$`. Or even `.*\bTARGET\b.*$` to match a row with a whole word.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte That is fair.  I actually was picking your brain to see if that was (by and large) the regex standard, and not just a feature of the handful of languages I've used that had that default.

Comment: @BlackVegetable: it's a legitime question. If you look at the Perl and at the POSIX syntaxes, you can have a good idea of what is a standart (or at least a widespread behavior).

Comment: Do we really need the ungreedy `?` ?

Comment: Yeah.. here the difference is.. if you have two `TARGET` words.. using ungreedy will match the first word.. and greedy will match second word..

Comment: @uraimo: it's not needed, but it may be more efficient since it avoids to match the whole line and to backtrack after. To complete this approach, writting: `(?=.+$).*?TARGET.*` can be interesting, since it fails quickly when it is not the last line.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I was surprised by your words `fails quickly`.. because lookahead will in general take more time.. check it.. :)

Comment: @karthikmanchala: no, lookaheads are not specialy slow. Only the way peoples use them is slow. Lookaheads can be used for several optimizations, example: `(?=[abc])(?:arborigen|bear|cacatoes)` (that avoids to test each branches of an alternation for each positions in the string).

Comment: @karthikmanchala: I use it here to avoid the cost of the non-greedy quantifier when it is not the last line.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte It sad to see someone with your reputation replying to a question that should be deleted. At least you could have warned the used.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte yes.. you are right.. lookaheads are not specialy slow.. but comparitively here.. they might degrade the performance actually.. you can check the number of steps taken [here](https://regex101.com/r/tC0tS5/1) `82` and [here](https://regex101.com/r/tC0tS5/2) `198`.. for same string :)

Comment: @PedroLobito: as you can see, the most important in an answer is not always the answer.

Comment: @karthikmanchala: oops you are right, I was thinking about that: `(?m)^(?=.+\z).*?TARGET.*` https://regex101.com/r/tC0tS5/3 to only test the first position of each lines

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte No, the most important is teaching new users how to ask before answering.

Comment: More important than just accumulating reputation, is making SO a website where future users can rely on, a website with proper questions.

Comment: @PedroLobito: If my goal was to accumulate reputation, I would have much more than that.